# Allow no selected value to be choose

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm getting an error where it says its empty.
But when my text field is empty, it doesn't show an error. I mean it allows empty fields, but not in **selected option**

Here's my html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" id="cakechoices" name="cakechoices" method="post"> 

<label for="dedicationT"> Dedication Text: </label> <input type="text" name="dedicationT" id="dedicationT" size="20" placeholder="Dedication" />

<label for="service_date"> Date: </label> <input type="date" id="service_date" name="service_date" value="M-D-YY"/>

<br> <label> Branch: <select name="branch_name" id="branch_selection" /> 
<option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>
<option value="B1">B1 </option>
<option value="B2">B2 </option>
<option value="B3">B3 </option>
<option value="B4">B4 </option>
</select> </label> 
</br>

<input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Order Now" />

</form>
```

Here's my php:

```
<?php

  $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
  if (!$link) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
  if (!mysql_select_db('myrnas')) {  die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error()); }

  session_start();
$dedicationT = $_POST['dedicationT'];
$service_date = $_POST['service_date'];
$branch_name = $_POST['branch_name'];

$query1 = "INSERT INTO order_cake (dedicationT, service_date, branch_name) VALUES ( '$dedicationT', '$service_date', '$branch_name');

if(@mysql_query($query1,$link))
   {  echo "Done!";  }  
   else {  print '<p> <h1> Somethings wrong, failed to connect!!!. GAD WHY!?! </h1> '.mysql_error().'</p>';  }

?>
```

This is my error : 
Undefined index: Branch_name in  **D:\Xampp\htdocs\system\customize\ordersent.php** on line **4**

this is my Ajax same in the html file

```
function submit_order($form) {
    $.ajax({
      url   : "process/ordersent.php", 
      type  : "POST",
      cache : false,
      data  : $form.serialize(),
      success: function(response) {

        alert(response);
        if(response == "Done")  {
            window.location.href = "home.php";
          } 
      }
    });
  }


      $('#submit').click(function(){ /* when the submit button in the modal is clicked, submit the form */
        swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff5c33",
          confirmButtonText: "Order Now!",
          closeOnConfirm: false
        },


        function(isConfirm){
          if (isConfirm) {

            submit_order( $('#cakechoices'));
            //swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
          } 
        });

        return false;
      });
```

Hope somebody can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the "disabled" attribute. Just remove it and the post "branch_name" will be sent with empty value.

You are setting it as disabled and the result is that no $_POST['branch_name'] variable is sent at all.

Change it to:

```
<option selected value="">-- Select one --</option>
```

Comment: ohgad, why didn't i try it.. *hides eternally*  THank you so much!!

Comment: You are welcome DownCrow. Please accept the answer if you consider it correct